# Performing ICP between Pointclouds in C++

Tags: ros, c++, icp, rosbag, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi-

I'm trying to create a script that takes in 2 bag files (fixed_frame and camera_frame), converts the ROS sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 data to pcl/PointCloud data, performs ICP between the pointcloud in fixed_frame and all the pointclouds in camera_frame, and publishes the results. Here is my code so far:

```
// Includes listed here

ros::Publisher _pub;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud_in; 

void fixed_frame_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& pc2_msg) {

  // Convert the sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 data to pcl/PointCloud
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_in(
                           new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>
                           );
  pcl::fromROSMsg ( *pc2_msg, *cloud_in );


}

void camera_frame_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& next_pc2_msg) {
 
  // Convert the sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 data to pcl/PointCloud
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud2_in(
                           new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>
                           );
  pcl::fromROSMsg ( *next_pc2_msg, *cloud2_in );

  // Perform ICP
  pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> icp;
  icp.setInputCloud(cloud2_in);
  icp.setInputTarget(cloud_in);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> Final;
  icp.align(Final);

  // Convert the pcl/PointCloud to sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 output;
  pcl::toROSMsg( *cloud2_in, output );
  // Publish the results
  _pub.publish( output );

}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

  // Initialize ROS
  ros::init (argc, argv, "my_script");
  ros::NodeHandle n( "~" );

  // Create ROS subscriber for fixed_frame topic
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe(
                    "/sr/pointcloud2/raw",
                    1,
                    fixed_frame_cb
                    );

  // Create ROS subscriber for camera_frame topic
  ros::Subscriber sub2 = n.subscribe(
                     "/sr/pointcloud2/raw",
                     1,
                     camera_frame_cb
                     );

  // Create ROS publisher for transformed pointcloud
  _pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>(
                           "/iml_transform_point_cloud/transformed_point_cloud",
                           1
                           );

  // Spin
  ros::spin ();
}
```

I'm getting a lot of errors when I run 'make'. New to ros and c++, so I think these might just be syntax problems. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Make errors:

> mdegges@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script$
> make mkdir -p bin cd build && cmake
> -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake
> .. [rosbuild] Building package
> my_script
> -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build/devel
> -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/groovy
> -- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy
> -- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
> -- catkin 0.5.63 [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
> [rosbuild] Including
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
> -- Configuring done
> -- Generating done CMake Warning:   Manually-specified variables were not
> used by the project:
>
> ```
> CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
> ```
>
> -- Build files have been written to: /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build
> cd build && make  make[1]: Entering
> directory
> `/home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build' make[2]: Entering directory` /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build'
> make[3]: Entering directory
> `/home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build'
> [  0%] Built target
> rospack_genmsg_libexe make[3]:
> Entering directory
> `/home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build'
> [  0%] Built target
> rosbuild_precompile make[3]: Entering
> directory
> `/home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build'
> make[3]: Entering directory
> `/home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build'
> [100%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/my_script.dir/src/example.cpp.o
> /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/src/example.cpp:
> In function ‘void
> camera_frame_cb(const
> PointCloud2ConstPtr&)’:
> /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/src/example.cpp:37:30:
> error: no matching function for call
> to
> ‘pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ,
> pcl::PointXYZ>::setInputTarget(pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ&)’
> /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/src/example.cpp:37:30:
> note: candidate is:
> /opt/ros/groovy/include/pcl-1.6/pcl/registration/impl/registration.hpp:42:1:
> note: void
> pcl::Registration<PointSource,
> PointTarget>::setInputTarget(const
> PointCloudTargetConstPtr&) [with
> PointSource = pcl::PointXYZ,
> PointTarget = pcl::PointXYZ,
> pcl::Registration<PointSource,
> PointTarget>::PointCloudTargetConstPtr
> = boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ >]
> /opt/ros/groovy/include/pcl-1.6/pcl/registration/impl/registration.hpp:42:1:
> note:   no known conversion for
> argument 1 from
> ‘pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ’ to
> ‘const PointCloudTargetConstPtr& {aka
> const boost::shared_ptr<const
> pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ >&}’ In
> file included from
> /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:32:0,
> from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/ros.h:45,
> from /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/src/example.cpp:1:
> /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:
> In member function ‘void
> ros::Publisher::publish(const M&)
> const [with M =
> sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_std::allocator<void
>
> > ]’: /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/src/example.cpp:45:24:
> > instantiated from here
> > /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7:
> > warning: comparison with string
> > literal results in unspecified
> > behaviour [-Waddress] make[3]: ***
> > [CMakeFiles/my_script.dir/src/example.cpp.o]
> > Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory
> > `/home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_script.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build'
> > make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]:
> > Leaving directory
> > `/home/mdegges/ros_workspace/iml_ros/my_script/build'
> > make: *** [all] Error 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60324/performing-icp-between-pointclouds-in-c++/) by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-04-09**:
Please edit your question with the errors you're seeing. It is very hard to help you without seeing what the problem is.

**Comment by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) on 2013-04-09**:
Ok- I posted the make errors on pastie: http://pastie.org/7397787

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2013-04-09**:
cannot open the page on pastie. why don't you just paste the error here? and you should also provide you CMakeLists.txt file

**Comment by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) on 2013-04-09**:
Sorry- edited the question with the errors included. The CMakeLists.txt file is the default, except I added a line at the bottom to make the script executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out. I just had some syntax errors- for ex, when I defined the global variable 'cloud_in', I forgot to make it a pointer.

---

Originally posted by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) with karma: 57 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrgen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31940/jrgen/) on 2017-09-29**:
How did you get the two .bag files into your program?
I tried
rosbag play -l 2017-06-07-13-49-48.bag 2017-06-07-14-05-40.bag /camera/depth/points:=icp/input/raw
But that doesn't work.